# Using osg (OpenSceneGraph) models in rviz?

Tags: ros, rviz, robot-model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to show meshes in rviz and the mesh is originally an OpenSceneGraph model (.osg). My previous conversion pipeline was to use osgconv to convert to 3ds and wings3d to convert to collada dae. That worked a couple of months ago but stopped working (nothing is displayed) in a recent update.

So do anybody have a working and recently tested conversion receipt for this only using Linux (Ubuntu)? Or any suggestion about what to test? I tested meshlab and got the object but no textures.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63027/using-osg-(openscenegraph)-models-in-rviz?/) by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1339 on 2013-05-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you mean this stopped working with a recent RViz update? There was a change in RViz that could cause this - it now interprets the 'unit' property in collada files. If this is set wrong, your meshes could be too large or too small to see in RViz. Check your collada files for that.

---

Originally posted by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) with karma: 1444 on 2013-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-05-19**:
Yes, it stopped working in a recent rviz update but I do not know exactly when. I will check the unit property.

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-05-19**:
Changing  the unit definition of meter from 0.01 to 1.0 solved the problem with my old Collada files. The Wings3d export to Collada works OK. I am still interested in alternative conversion paths which could give nicer handling of material properties.

**Comment by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) on 2013-05-19**:
The tools you use have parameters that control the scaling, they should do the job without manual adjustments.

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-05-19**:
That means that I have to learn the tools... And I really thought my original format was unit less.  So it was really a surprise for me that units are added in some formats.